# Can my application be compatible with multiple versions of MPI

Tags: mpi, intel-mpi

I have an application that uses MPI_COMM_WORLD. I'm building the application with HPC Pack 2008 R2 MPI and everything works fine on my local and most PCs.

Occasionally when installing on a different PC I will run into issues with competing versions of MPI (e.g. Intel). This is usually solved by prepending my HPC version to the PATH.

I have recently hit an issue that I can't work around.

My MPI is first in the path, but I'm getting an error "link library mkl_intel_thread.dll" cannot be found.  This tells me the app is looking at the Intel version.

[where mpiexec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXE1p.png)
[mkl_thread not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae500.png)

So my general questions are:

1. Is there a version of MPI that is compatibly with all others?
2. Or is there a way to compile my application in a way that I can
   ensure it looks for the right MPI library?
3. Or is there a way to compile to make the application MPI agnostic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It fails to find Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL), which is not a dependency of Intel MPI (rather, the opposite is true, depending on how you link the BLACS component).

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of MPI is the [MPI standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/). This means as long as you stick to a certain version of the MPI standard, your programm should be compatible with MPI standard compliant implementations.

The missing Math Kernel Library has nothing to do with MPI incompatibility.